# midi sound on my html page

Tags: javascript, html, audio, midi

I'm working on my html page, where i want to play midi sound (.mid) but i dont know how to do so. Is there any method where i can play midi sound on the page.

This is the code, i'm working on. Please tell me the changes i need to do

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>HTML Layouts using DIV, SPAN</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100%">
 <div style="background-color:#b5dcb3; width:100%">
  <center><h1>Sonification</h1></center>
  </div>
 <div style="background-color:#aaa; height:2000px;width:610px;float:left;">
<center><img src="image\so.jpg" alt="Sonification"></center>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<center><h3>Sound_1</h3></center>
<table style="width:40%">
<tr>
    <td><audio id="player" controls> <source src="audio\final.mid" type="audio/ogg"> <source src="final" type="audio/mpeg">Audio</audio>
    </td>
    <td><audio id="player" controls> <source src="audio\final.mid" type="audio/ogg"> <source src="final" type="audio/mpeg">Audio</audio>
    </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: a .mid file is not audio/ogg mimetype - I don't think midi audio is supported (without a plugin) anymore - or perhaps it's simply the \ in audio\final.mid instead of / in the path (the internet and every OS except windows uses / rather than \ in path names) - try audio/final.mid ... but I don't hold out much hope as it is not an ogg file

Answer (score 0):

To play midi, you have to use: https://mudcu.be/midi-js/

The `<audio>` element doesn't support it.